# Error al ejecutar clase que usa archivos .jar

Tags: java, eclipse

Estoy tratando de ejecutar una clase que utiliza ficheros `.jar`, ya los agregué al build path de eclipse y los reconoce, ya que no me da error en la instancia, pero cuando intento correr la aplicación me da este error:

> Check that you have the com.ibm.mq.pcf.jar in your classpath along
>   with any other jar files that may be needed. [Root exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/disthub2/spi/ClientTranslate]

Ya me aseguré que esté el archivo `com.ibm.mq.pcf.jar`. Entiendo que tal vez podría ser el fichero MANIFEST del jar.

Alguien que me pueda ayudar con esta duda? Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error te indica el problema, la clase com.ibm.disthub2.spi.ClientTranslate.

Añade la librería dhbcore.jar

Comment: Muchas gracias Pablo!

Comment: Realmente llevo poco tiempo aprendiendo java, me podrías decir como identificaste que esa librería era la que faltaba?

Comment: Si te fijas en la última parte de la traza de error, verás que se hace referencia a una clase java, com/ibm/disthub2/spi/ClientTranslate, que es necesaria para que funcione la aplicación. Debería buscar las diferencias entre ClassNotFoundException, que suele darse al compilar, y NoClassDefFoundException, que suele ser en ejecución y por faltar alguna librería que tú no usas de forma directa, pero sí otra librería que has incluído.

Comment: Y, ya para encontrar la librería concreta, hay webs que te dicen en qué librería puedes encontrar una clase completa, como http://www.findjar.com/